# can i use '>' css selector in protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, protractor

How can I solve this problem? This part of the test will be not Angular based.

```
function Menu(container) {
    this.container = container;
    this.elements = this.getItems();
}

Menu.prototype.getItems = function() {
    var arr = this.container.$('> li');
    ...
};
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ascope) experimental CSS selector (would not work on IE):

> The :scope CSS pseudo-class matches the elements that are a reference
>   point for selectors to match against.

```
this.container.$(":scope > li");
```

Alternatively, you can use [`by.xpath()` locator](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath):

```
this.container.element(by.xpath("./li"));
```

Comment: :scope is great!